# How to display tags with post_content

Tags: tags, post-content

I have this code to display the content of a specific post outside the loop (actually in the archive.php template file). How do I include the tags?

```
<?php
$my_id = 1576;
$post_id_1576= get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_1576->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `get_the_tags($my_id)`, example :

```
$posttags = get_the_tags($my_id);
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

Refering to [WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/)

Comment: This isn't working... `$my_id = 1110;
$post_id_1110 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_1110->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
$tags = $post_id_1110->get_the_tags;
$tags = apply_filters('get_the_tags', $tags);
$tags = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $tags);
echo $tags;
echo $content; `

Comment: When I say outside the loop, I mean not in a page template, hence why i'm using the post ID.

Comment: just use get_the_tags(1110);

Comment: @Pete, the post object (a `WP_Post` instance) does not have a property named `get_the_tags`. And you could actually just do `echo get_the_tags( $my_id ); echo $content;` .. There's also [`the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/) which displays/`echo` the post tags.

Comment: @SallyCJ it displays "Array"

Comment: No luck with this... `$my_id = 1576;
$post_id_1576= get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_1576->post_content;
echo get_the_tags( $my_id ); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content; 
echo get_the_tags(1576);`

Comment: Lol sorry, @Pete... You need to manually loop through the array items (the term/`WP_Term` objects returned by `get_the_tags()`) (perhaps @Gregory could give an example). But why not, use `the_tags()`, if you don't need special formatting?

Comment: Hello, I added a more clear example in my answear.